# django integrityerror: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "django_content_type_pkey"

Tags: python, django, database, migration, integrity

I've been working on this project on my desktop, upon updating my local repo with the github repo, I tried to migrate the changes I had made on my desktop to the database (added fields). I'm not getting this error and im not sure why. Detail: key(id)=1 already exists. I've tried looking up solutions but could not find any accurate ones. Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
"django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique 
constraint "django_content_type_pkey" DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists."
```

Comment: how to you a make migration? your commands..

Comment: python manage.py migrate

Comment: in thish case, i simple delete all values in table... thish table contain not critical data

Comment: How do i do this? I think I tried this by using sqlflush but that doesn't work

Comment: I dropped the database and re added it, error has been fixed. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

you can try this sql statement：SELECT setval('table name_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table name)+1)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).